# When the bootstrap css would reset the a:visited link style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

Recently I'm using `bootstrap`, find the `bootstrap.css` would clear the `a:visited` style,

like: http://jsfiddle.net/FbCMH/

So some people complain that it's hard to tell part the link they visited on my page.

Why the bootstrap would do this?

After clear the visited style, they can also add its owner visited style, why they just abandon it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the less version of Bootstrap 3, you can try [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/MonkeyDo/60eac7106414ba8d9405) I made as a base, copied below:

```
@link-hover-color: lightblue; //Change this to your needs
a{  
color: @link-color;
&:hover{
    color: @link-hover-color;
}
&:hover, &:focus{
    text-decoration: none;
}
&:visited:not(.btn){
    color: @link-visited-color;
}

// Exceptions to :visited state
// Comment out to taste
&.list-group-item:visited{
    color:@list-group-link-color;
    &.active,
    &.active:hover,
    &.active:focus {
        color: @list-group-active-color;
    }
}
.navbar-default &.navbar-brand:visited{
    color:@navbar-default-brand-color;
}
.navbar-inverse &.navbar-brand:visited{
    color:@navbar-inverse-brand-color;
}
.nav-tabs > li > &:visited{
    color: @link-color;
}
.nav-pills > li > &:visited{
    color: @link-color;
}
.nav-pills > li.active > &:visited{
  &,
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    color: @nav-pills-active-link-hover-color;
  }
}
.dropdown-menu > li > &:visited{
   color: @dropdown-link-color;
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    color: @dropdown-link-hover-color;
    background-color: @dropdown-link-hover-bg;
  }
}
.dropdown-menu > li.disabled > &:visited{
  &,
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    color: @dropdown-link-disabled-color;
  }
}
.pager > li > &:visited,
.pagination > li > &:visited{
    &,
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
        color: @link-color;
    }
}
.pagination > .active > &:visited{
    &,
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
        color: @pagination-active-color;
    }
}
.pagination > .disabled  > &:visited{
    &,
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
        color: @pagination-disabled-color;
    }
}
&.alert-link:visited{
    color: inherit;
}
}
```

Comment: I copied the gist over, in case the link dies someday, Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If it's really that much of a problem, you can change the `a:visited` colour yourself.

Just go into bootstrap and do it, or if you've got a custom .css file, load it after `bootstrap.css` in the `<head>` section and then within it put `a:visited{color:#000 !important;}`. This will change the colour (obviously change it to a colour you want).

Comment: You shouldn't use `!important` when overriding a framework's CSS rules, using the same selectors and adding the custom file after the framework's will add enough weight for the new rule to be applied, also OP is asking about the absence of the CSS rule in Bootstrap so there's actually nothing to override

Answer (score 0):

be sure that you have no scaffold.css which was created by the scaffolding job itself. it has the visited styles that you are looking for. maybe.